# Взаимодействие 'Raycast' с 'UI' компонентами по 'Tag'

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Каким образом реализовать взаимодействие курсора с 'UI' компонентами выборка которых происходит по их 'Tag'?

Пытался реализовать это так:

```
    Ray _ray = MyCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        Debug.Log("Complete!");
```

Результат: Курсор реагирует на все UI компоненты булев 'Raycast Target' которого является положительным.

Comment: А вас не устроит банальный `EventTrigger` для элементов, который есть у кнопки `UI` по дефолту, а остальным просто добавить? и не нужен никакой луч

Comment: А также, вроде бы должны работать стандартные события `OnMouseOver/OnMouseEnter/OnMouseDown` и т.д. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В чем смысл луча в данном коде?
Если в том, чтобы с его помощью определять, с каким объектом происходит взаимодействие, то:

```
Ray _ray = MyCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(_ray, out hit)) {
    if (hit.gameObject.tag == "something") {
        if (UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            Debug.Log("Complete!");
    }
}
```

Не очень круто, но в этом был смысл луча?

**UPD:**
Тогда можно оставить так через луч:

```
Ray _ray = MyCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(_ray, out hit) && hit.gameObject.tag == "something") {
    //if (UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) более не требуется.
    Debug.Log("Complete!");
}
```

Но на мой взгляд лучше избежать использования луча даже простыми event, либо EventTrigger, как предложили в комментариях, либо еще как-то.

Comment: Вы абсолютно верно определили смысл реализации луча в данном контексте. 

Если есть способ который более осмысленно и логично может реализовать нужный мне результат я хочу его использовать с помощью вашего, возможно, объяснения.

Comment: Если уж использовать луч, то можно вообще не работать с системой событий, поскольку с помощью луча уже есть объект с проверкой на тег и можно приступать к действиям. В какой части жизненного цикла находится этот код?